# Apache Cordova, Visual Studio 2015, Xcode 8.3 cannot remotebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, visual-studio-2015

It has been a year since I first build the app, and of course my iPhone software has updated since then.  With that I was informed that I needed to update Xcode in order to get the right platform to get a release version for my cordova app updates.  Updating xcode required me to update the OS to Sierra on the mac.  After that, I have been unable to remotebuild even my debug version, which I had been able to do before.

My constant issue right now is that when I build the app in remote build it keeps adding "ios": "4.0.1" to the platforms.json file, but the error I receive is that with xcode 8.3 I need 4.3.0 or greater.

I cannot figure out how to update this value.  I have upgraded npm, node, everything that I can think of.  Nothing changes the value, and I can't seem to find anyone else with my problem.

Any help or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: I have the same error, did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution.  My solution was to move all of my coding to the Mac and run apache cordova natively on the mac removing Visual Studio from the equation.

Answer (score 0):

First, open up project platforms folder and delete `ios` folder. Then update cordova on your development machine and Mac.

```
For Mac    :  $ sudo npm install -g cordova 
For Windows: npm install -g cordova
```

Just check whether your files getting deployed to the Mac build folder path. If so, open up the project using XCode.

Then build your project using XCODE. Most probably there will be an error to choose the development team. Once you select the account or the team fom dropdown list you can deploy the app without any issues.

That worked for me. Hope this will help you too.

**Another way**: Navigate to platforms folder -> platforms.json. Check the IOS version. Change it to 4.3.0 and delete the ios folder and add IOS 4.3.0 via command prompt.

packages.json

```
{
    "android": "5.1.1",
    "ios": "4.3.0"
}
```

in cmd Run

```
cordova platform add ios@4.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, be ready for many actions to be done but in the end it works. )

1. Update your XCode to `8.3.3` without worry.
2. Then be sure to update your `remotebuild` to the latest version that is currently `2.1.3` by running `sudo npm i remotebuild -g` on your Mac.
3. Get back to your development machine with `Visual Studio` and run some command line utility in `administrator mode`. Open you `cordova` folder from there.
4. Execute `cordova platform rm ios` to remove the current `ios` version under `cordova`. It's also advised to remove the android one by `cordova platform rm android`.
5. Update the version of CLI you use for builidng on `Visual Studio`. Currently it's `7.0.1`. There were people that claimed that `6.5.0` also works but in my setup `7.0.1` works as well.
6. Get back to your command line and run `cordova platform add ios@4.4.0`, This is the minimal `cordova ios` that supports the cordova `7.0.1`.
7. In case you removed `android` as well then run `cordova platform add android@6.0.0`. There are more progressive versions of `cordova android` but I found them not working.
8. Now get back to your Mac and remove the following folder `~/.taco-remote/node_modules`.
9. In case you don't see this `.taco-remote` folder it's the hidden one so run in command line of your Mac `com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true` and then `killall Finder` to close all instances of `Finder`. Afterwards `.taco-remote` folder should be visible under your user folder `~/`.
10. Now go back to `Visual Studio` and open `Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova` and run `Clear Cordova cache`.
11. Now run your `ios` and it should succeed.
12. In case you run afterwards your `android` build and it fails on something like `Android platform already added` run the `Clear cordova cache again` and then your `android` build also should succeed.
13. From this point both `ios` and `android` builds should work.

Whooof. )

Good luck!

BTW, most of this solution came from [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues/26).